# Copy chain caracters in dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I'm trying something for training in programming. As im spreaking french, my variables might seems weird but well. I've put my whole code under this. The section bugging is "Liste * CreerListe". Thats where the magic happens and where the titanic goes down. For some reason, it either doesnt let me put the char array named S in my Class liste or it works but puts like 8 times "1/2" after it. Any ideas on why and how to fix it?

```
///------------------------------------------
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Struct.h"

int B64(int v)
{
 if (v < 26) return ('A' + v);
 if (v < 52) return ('a' + (v - 26));
 if (v < 62) return ('0' + (v - 52));
 if (v == 62) return '+';
 return '/';
}


LISTE*CreerListe(char v[])
{
 LISTE* mot;
 char *temp = v;
 mot = (LISTE*)malloc(sizeof(LISTE));
 //mot->s = {};
 //printf("%i", strlen(v));

strncpy(mot->s, temp, strlen(temp));
 return mot;
}

void ConversionB64(LISTE* v)
{
 int longueur=0, i=0, j = 0 , temp = 0,decalage=0;
 longueur = strlen(v->s);
 for (i = 0, j = 8; i < longueur; ++i)
 {
  temp = (v->s[i])<<(j*(longueur-i))+temp;
 }
 decalage = (longueur * 6);
 for (decalage; decalage>-1;decalage-=6)
 {
  printf("%c", B64((temp >> decalage) & 0x03f));
 }
 printf("\n");

}


main()
{
 LISTE*mot;

 char v[] = "Brutus";
 //printf("%i", strlen(v));
 mot =CreerListe(&v);

 //int f = 0, z = 0;
 //f = strlen(mot->s);
 //z = strlen(v);
 //printf("%d, %d",f,z );
 //ConversionB64(mot);
 printf("%s", mot->s);
 _getch();
}
/--------------------- Here is LISTE (struct.h)
#ifndef LISTE_H
#define LISTE_H

typedef struct Liste
{
 char s[];

}LISTE;


LISTE *CreerListe(char v[]);


#endif
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. For example, we need to see the definition of `LISTE`.

Comment: `strncpy(mot->s, temp, len);` That is wrong. It will copy only `len` characters which means the NUL terminator is not copied resulting in `mot->s` not being a valid string. The `strncpy` `n` parameter is generally supposed to be the length of the *destination* not the *source*.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum . Im not yet used to this forum. Yes, it was a version i've tried. Here is the one I oroginally made.

Comment: `char s[];` That is wrong too. That is a zero length array. Obviously not what you need right? And the new version you have given is basically the same as the previous version. It's still coying `strlen(temp)` which is what the previous version did except it first saved that same length into a variable.

Comment: I want the array to be dynamic. That no matter what i write, it takes the good lenght.

Comment: A zero length array is not magically a dynamically sized array. You need to allocate the right memory size for it. You allocate `sizeof(LISTE)` which is not a dynamic length in any way. If you don't believe that then simply print out the value of `sizeof(LISTE)`.

Comment: @kaylum, im not here to doubt you in any way. Im here to understand and i would appreciate it a lot if you could give further explanation on how it could be done if not like that. The sizeof(LISTE) has been used in a work Im basing this practice on so this is the only knowledge i have.

Comment: Can you provide the typedef for `LISTE`? I guess it is inside "struct.h". I suspect that the length of the string must be taken into account for `LISTE.s`.